# Delete `dtype: object` in pandas DataFrame print

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the code I have:

```
def boba_recs(lat, lng):
    f1 = pd.read_csv("./boba_final.csv") 
    user_loc = Point(lng, lat) # converts user lat/long to point object
    # makes dataframe of distances between each boba place and the user loc
    f1['Distance'] = [user_loc.distance(Point(xy)) for xy in zip(f1.Longitude, f1.Lat)]
    # grabs the three smallest distances
    boba = f1.nsmallest(3, 'Distance').set_index('Name') # sets index to name
    return(": " + boba['Address'])
```

This returns:

```
Name
Coco Bubble Tea            : 129 E 45th St New York, NY 10017
Gong Cha                   : 75 W 38th St, New York, NY 10018
Smoocha Tea & Juice Bar      : 315 5th Ave New York, NY 10016
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

Almost perfect except I want to get rid of the "Name: Address, dtype: object" row. I've tried a few things and it just won't go away without messing up the format of everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'Address'` is the name of the `pd.Series` and `'Name'` is the name of the index

Try:

```
s.rename_axis(None).rename(None)

Coco Bubble Tea            : 129 E 45th St New York, NY 10017
Gong Cha                   : 75 W 38th St, New York, NY 10018
Smoocha Tea & Juice Bar      : 315 5th Ave New York, NY 10016
dtype: object
```

Or I'd rewrite your function

```
def boba_recs(lat, lng):
    f1 = pd.read_csv("./boba_final.csv") 
    user_loc = Point(lng, lat) # converts user lat/long to point object
    # makes dataframe of distances between each boba place and the user loc
    f1['Distance'] = [user_loc.distance(Point(xy)) for xy in zip(f1.Longitude, f1.Lat)]
    # grabs the three smallest distances
    boba = f1.nsmallest(3, 'Distance').set_index('Name') # sets index to name
    return(": " + boba['Address']).rename_axis(None).rename(None)
```

If you want a string

```
def boba_recs(lat, lng):
    f1 = pd.read_csv("./boba_final.csv") 
    user_loc = Point(lng, lat) # converts user lat/long to point object
    # makes dataframe of distances between each boba place and the user loc
    f1['Distance'] = [user_loc.distance(Point(xy)) for xy in zip(f1.Longitude, f1.Lat)]
    # grabs the three smallest distances
    boba = f1.nsmallest(3, 'Distance').set_index('Name') # sets index to name
    temp = (": " + boba['Address']).rename_axis(None).__repr__()
    return temp.rsplit('\n', 1)[0]
```

Comment: yeah i tried this but it still has the dtype: object portion.

Comment: When you return a `pd.Series` it will show up on your screen with the string that is returned from the `__repr__` method.  That method is written to return the `dtype` at the end as part of the description.  My question to you is, do you want to return a string that is properly formatted?  Or do you want to return a pandas series object?  If you want the pandas series object, then you're going to have to live with the `dtype` in the description.

Comment: a properly formatted string, it doesn't necessarily have to be a series

Comment: @user3611375 don't forget to accept if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a row. It's a description of the data you are printing. Try printing just the `.values` and you will see.

```
[Coco Bubble Tea            : 129 E 45th St New York, NY 10017
Gong Cha                   : 75 W 38th St, New York, NY 10018
Smoocha Tea & Juice Bar      : 315 5th Ave New York, NY 10016]
```

**Update** Based on your comment:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(your_series))
Name
Coco Bubble Tea            : 129 E 45th St New York, NY 10017
Gong Cha                   : 75 W 38th St, New York, NY 10018
Smoocha Tea & Juice Bar      : 315 5th Ave New York, NY 10016
```

Comment: Again, not totally ideal because then it would be a list instead of a return string. And sure, I can iterate through it, but if there's something I can do to format it directly from the dataframe, i highly prefer that.